# Find String and Offset Data VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm at a standstill here. What I'm trying to do is search Column A for a cell that begins with a number. Then from that location, look in the cells above it until it finds one that begins with "L". Finally, move the cell that begins with a number to the next blank cell to the right of the "L" cell. And then repeat until there are no more cells that begin with a number left in Column A. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Code_Relocate()

Dim ws1         As Worksheet
Dim codecheck   As Boolean
Dim lastrow     As Long
Dim i           As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow

codecheck = Range("A" & i).Value Like "[0-9]*"

    If codecheck = True Then
        'Search from this point up, find first cell that begins with "L" and move code to the next blank cell on the right
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Here's what the before and after would look like:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Will it always be a 1 to 1 relationship?

Comment: @ScottCraner No - I should have put that in my before and after image. I'm sorry. I updated it.

Comment: How large is your data table, and are the only things in the table items that start with either "L" or a number?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It varies, but it can be up to 5,000 rows. And yes, either start with an "L" or is a number.

Comment: OK, Scott's solution should be fine.  For larger data sets, a different approach might be faster.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for checking it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Code_Relocate()

Dim ws1         As Worksheet
Dim temp        As String
Dim lastrow     As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim tempArr()   As String
Dim j           As Long


Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(ws1.Range("A" & i)) And Len(ws1.Range("A" & i)) > 0 Then
        temp = ws1.Range("A" & i) & " " & temp
        ws1.Range("A" & i).ClearContents
    ElseIf Left(ws1.Range("A" & i), 1) = "L" Then
        tempArr = Split(Trim(temp))
        For j = LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr)
            If tempArr(j) <> "" Then
                ws1.Cells(i, 2 + j) = --tempArr(j)
            End If
        Next j

        temp = ""
        Erase tempArr
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the following: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch at temp = "" I updated my original with different images to show that it's not always 1 to 1.

Comment: It did! That's perfect. Thank you so much! Sorry for the delay - had some flooding in the basement but we're good now.